# Login form using PHP and permissions

Tags: php, authentication

I have a question, I have a database field called "is-admin", and I have a login form, what I want:

For example user have The value "1" in  "is-admin" field and clicks on submit button he will enter to "home1.php", but if he has "0" in is-admin he will enter to "home.php".

My question is how to do that using PHP?

Comment: Set a session variable and send them to the page with `header`, on the page check the session variable.

Comment: @chris85 agreed. This will allow your program to have the access to the variables across all pages. you have to use `session_start();` before you are able to access the `$_SESSION` values.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch a user array based on username eg. "SELECT is-admin FROM users WHERE username = $username"

then save this value in var e.g. $user_status and create simple if/else statement e.g.

```
if($user_status = 1) {
    header("Location: 'home1.php'");
    exit;
}else {
    header("Location: 'home.php'");
    exit;
}
```

when using header() make sure that output buffering is on, otherwise this this particular example won't work.

Comment: Thank you ! this is what i want .